# Как пройтись по всем Label формы в цикле?(Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic

Подскажите пожалуйста(я в тупике)
Допустим у меня имеется в форме несколько Лейблов
Label1
Label2
Label3
Label4
Label5
Как мне в цикле пройтись по ним и каждому дать к примеру текстовое значение

```
Dim i As Integer = 1
Do While i < 6
  Label.Text = "Обработано" -  КАК В ЭТУ СТРОЧКУ ПРИПЕНДЮЛИТЬ i
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Леиблы формы лежат в коллекции контролов [формы](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx), поэтому тебе надо перебрать эту коллекцию и найти объекты типа [Lable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx)

```
Dim i As Integer = 1

For Each control As Control In Me.Controls
    If control.GetType() Is GetType(Label) Then
        Dim currentLable As Label = CType(control, Label)
        currentLable.Text = "Обработано " & i
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

Примените массив меток `Label(i).Text = "Обработано"`